# Test fails with karma, gulp, and angular (from yeoman fountainJs seed)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, yeoman

I try to customize an angular project based on the FountainJS seed (basic angular 1.6 app with bower, js es5, sass and hello world application).

Problem is that tests fails when I run a `gulp test`:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) hello component should render hello world FAILED
        forEach@bower_components/angular/angular.js:402:24
        loadModules@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4880:12
        createInjector@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4802:30
        WorkFn@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3161:60
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
        bower_components/angular/angular.js:4921:53
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.004 secs / 0.011 secs)
15 03 2017 14:44:20.072:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
15 03 2017 14:44:20.073:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
15 03 2017 14:44:20.082:DEBUG [launcher]: Process PhantomJS exited with code 0
15 03 2017 14:44:20.082:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir C:\Users\marmin-t\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-62828717
15 03 2017 14:44:20.089:DEBUG [launcher]: Finished all browsers
[14:44:20] 'karma:single-run' errored after 4.04 s
[14:44:20] Error: Failed 1 tests.
    at C:\xxx\angular1-front-seed\gulp_tasks\karma.js:15:22
    at removeAllListeners (C:\xxx\angular1-front-seed\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:380:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\xxx\angular1-front-seed\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:391:9)
    at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at emitCloseNT (net.js:1537:8)
    at nextTickCallbackWith1Arg (node.js:431:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:394:17)
[14:44:20] 'test' errored after 4.46 s
```

I use a custom bootstrap for async configuration loading as you can see in my `index.html`:

```
<script>
  // inspired from https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data
  // Async load config/config.json
  (function() {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

    fetchData().then(bootstrapApplication);

    function fetchData() {
      var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
      var $http = initInjector.get("$http");
      var $log = initInjector.get("$log");

      return $http.get("/config/config.json").then(function(response) {
        app.constant("config", response.data);
      }, function(errorResponse) {
        $log.error('an error occurred while loading configuration', error);
      });
    }

    function bootstrapApplication() {
      angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
        document.body.className = 'ng-app';
      });
    }
  }());
</script>
```

I have the default hello component generated by yeoman generator:

`hello.js`:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .component('app', {
    templateUrl: 'app/hello.html',
    controller: function(config) {
      this.hello = 'Hello World!';
      this.config = config;
    }
  });
```

`hello.html`

```
<h1>{{ $ctrl.hello }}</h1>
<h2>Config:</h2>
<pre>{{ $ctrl.config | json }}</pre>
```

and the `hello.spec.js`

```
describe('hello component', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app', function($provide) {
    $provide.factory('app', function() {
      return {
        templateUrl: 'app/hello.html'
      };
    });
  }));
  it('should render hello world', angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    var element = $compile('<app>Loading...</app>')($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    var h1 = element.find('h1');
    expect(h1.html()).toEqual('Hello World!');
  }));
});
```

I enabled the debug log level for karma, and here is the file loaded at tests startup:

```
15 03 2017 14:44:16.614:DEBUG [web-server]: Instantiating middleware
15 03 2017 14:44:16.691:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/src/assets/**/*" does not match any file.
15 03 2017 14:44:16.715:DEBUG [preprocessor.html2js]: Processing "C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/src/app/hello.html".
15 03 2017 14:44:16.715:DEBUG [preprocessor.html2js]: Processing "C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/src/index.html".
15 03 2017 14:44:16.739:DEBUG [karma-angular-filesort]: Sorted files:
        C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
        C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
        C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
        C:/xxx/github/angular1-front-seed/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-shim/shim.js
        C:/xxx/github/angular1-front-seed/bower_components/angular/angular.js
        C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js
        C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
        C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/src/app/hello.html.js
        C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/src/index.html.js
        C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/.tmp/routes.js
        C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/.tmp/app/hello.js
        C:/xxx/angular1-front-seed/.tmp/app/hello.spec.js
```

What is missing? any idea?

Thx!